# ¿Cómo guardar la información de un archivo txt en un json usando python?

Tags: python-3.x, json, linux, archivo

¡Hola! :D

Con ayuda del comando "iw" en Linux, hago un monitoreo de las redes Wi-Fi disponibles, el resultado lo guardo en un archivo txt. Todos los datos que se guardan, debo de separarlos y juntarlos en un json.

Esta es una muestra del archivo:

```
BSS 88:15:44:39:48:66(on wlp1s0) -- associated
    last seen: 3905.256s [boottime]
    TSF: 16770805099 usec (0d, 04:39:30)
    freq: 2412
    beacon interval: 100 TUs
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1431)
    signal: -49.00 dBm
    last seen: 3492 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: Café Negro
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 
    DS Parameter set: channel 1
BSS c8:d7:19:d4:7d:b9(on wlp1s0)
    last seen: 3908.343s [boottime]
    TSF: 7141877017905 usec (82d, 15:51:17)
    freq: 5785
    beacon interval: 100 TUs
    capability: ESS Privacy (0x0011)
    signal: -91.00 dBm
    last seen: 405 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: MOUREY C4
    Supported rates: 6.0* 9.0 12.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 48.0 54.0
```

Este es el código que he realizado (No tengo mucha experiencia en Python):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import json
import datetime

# Variables

aps = {}
i = 0
mac_range = slice(4, 21)

with open('all_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

# Función para obtener las direcciones MAC
def getBSSID(text):
    bssid = [] 
    for line in text: 
        if line.startswith('BSS'): 
            mac = line[mac_range] 
            bssid.append(mac)
    return bssid

# Función para obtener el nombre de la red (SSID)
def getSSID(text):
    ssid = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    SSID'):
            name_ssid = line[7:len(line)].strip()
            ssid.append(name_ssid)
    return ssid

# Función para obtener el tiempo en que se identifico por última vez
def lastSeen(text):
    last_seen = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    last seen'):
            #print(line)
            seconds = line
            last_seen.append(seconds)
    return last_seen

def cleanLastSeen(lista):
    new_last_seen = []
    list_time = []
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if i%2!=0:
            new_last_seen.append(lista[i].strip())

    for element in new_last_seen:
         a = element.replace("last seen: ", "")#.replace("[boottime]", "")#.replace(" ", "")
         list_time.append(a)
    #return new_last_seen
    return list_time


# Función para obtener la potencia de la señal
def signal(text):
    signal = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    signal'):
            signal_dbm = line[8:len(line)].strip()
            signal.append(signal_dbm)
    return signal

def tsf(text):
    tsf = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    TSF'):
            tsf_data = line[5:len(line)].strip()
            tsf.append(tsf_data)
    return tsf

def freq(text):
    freq = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    freq'):
            freq_data = line[6:len(line)].strip()
            freq.append(freq_data)
    return freq

def beaconInterval(text):
    beacon_interval = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    beacon interval'):
            beacon_interval_data = line[17:len(line)].strip()
            beacon_interval.append(beacon_interval_data)
    return beacon_interval

def capability(text):
    capability = []
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('    capability'):
            capability_data = line[12:len(line)].strip()
            capability.append(capability_data)
    return capability

def supportedRates(text):
    supported_rates = []
    for line in text:
        if(line.startswith('    Supported rates')):
            supported_rates_data = line[17:len(line)].strip()
            supported_rates.append(supported_rates_data)
    return supported_rates

#Pendiente
def dsParameterSet(text):
    ds_parameter_set = []
    for line in text:
        if(line.startswith('    DS Parameter set')):
            ds_parameter_set_data = line[18:len(line)].strip()
            ds_parameter_set.append(ds_parameter_set_data)
        #else:
            #ds_parameter_set_data = ""
            #ds_parameter_set.append(ds_parameter_set_data)
    return ds_parameter_set

bssid = getBSSID(text)
ssid = getSSID(text)
signal = signal(text)
last_seen = lastSeen(text)
list_last_seen = cleanLastSeen(last_seen)
tsf = tsf(text)
freq = freq(text)
beacon_interval = beaconInterval(text)
capability = capability(text)
supported_rates = supportedRates(text)
#ds_parameter_set = dsParameterSet(text)

json_data = {"aps": []}


try:
    for i in range(len(bssid)):
        json_data["aps"].append({
            "mac_address": bssid[i],
            "ssid": ssid[i],
            "last_seen": list_last_seen[i],
            "signal": signal[i],
            "timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(),
            "tsf": tsf[i],
            "frequency": freq[i],
            "beacon_interval": beacon_interval[i],
            "capability": capability[i],
            "supported_rates": supported_rates[i],
            #"ds_parameter_set": ds_parameter_set[i]
            #"timestamp": ct
        })
except:
    Exception



print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, default=str))
```

Esta es una muestra al ejecutar el código:

```
{
    "aps": [
        {
            "mac_address": "88:15:44:39:48:66",
            "ssid": "BBNet2",
            "last_seen": "3492 ms ago",
            "signal": "-49.00 dBm",
            "timestamp": "2020-12-08 12:22:02.584492",
            "tsf": "16770805099 usec (0d, 04:39:30)",
            "frequency": "2412",
            "beacon_interval": "100 TUs",
            "capability": "ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1431)",
            "supported_rates": "1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0"

        },
        {
            "mac_address": "e8:ed:05:32:91:e0",
            "ssid": "AIKIDO DOJO\\x20",
            "last_seen": "3314 ms ago",
            "signal": "-37.00 dBm",
            "timestamp": "2020-12-08 12:22:02.584503",
            "tsf": "943151798510 usec (10d, 21:59:11)",
            "frequency": "2437",
            "beacon_interval": "100 TUs",
            "capability": "ESS Privacy SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0511)",
            "supported_rates": "1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 54.0"

        },
    ]
}
```

**El problema es que,** al principio todos los datos eran similares, pero llega un punto el que una red sí cuenta con cierto dato pero otra red no lo tiene.
Como por ejemplo, el dato `DS Parameter set`

***Entonces, mi duda es, ¿cómo puedo guardar la información de cada red adecuadamente teniendo en cuenta que los datos pueden estar o no estar?***

Espero puedan ayudarme con alguna idea.

¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La información de entrada es básicamente una lista de llaves y valores, que comienza con una línea especial, "BBS ", por lo que una estrategia es tomar la entrada, dividirla y poblar un diccionario con cada red tomando solo información de interés.

Si a una red le falta un dato, no es problema, pues ningun dato en especial es requerido.

Primero tengo un diccionario cuyas llaves son los datos que me interesa capturar, y cuyo valor es el nombre a usar en el json de salida:

```
claves =  {"bbs": "mac address",
           "ssid": "ssid",
           "last seen": "last_seen",
           "signal": "signal",
           "timestamp": "timestamp",
           "tsf": "tsf",
           "freq": "frequency",
           "beacon interval": "beacon_interval",
           "capability": "capability",
           "supported rates": "supported_rates"}
```

Tengo también una lista de diccionarios, con un diccionario por cada red. La variable `dic` corresponde a la red en proceso.

```
lista = []
dic = None
```

Luego recorre el archivo línea por línea. Cada vez que detecto una línea con "BBS ", agrego el diccionario actual a la lista y genero un nuevo diccionario, inicializado con el timestamp.

Cada linea la divido en dos para separar la llave del valor correspondiente. Si la llave está en el diccionario `claves`, entonces la agrego a `dic`, el diccionario de la red actual. Si no, la descarto.

Al momento de agregar, aprovecho de cambiar la llave original (`data seen`, por ejemplo) por la llave json (`data_seen`)

```
with open("all_data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[:4] == "BSS ":
            if dic:
                lista.append(dic)
            (llave, valor) = line.split(" ", 1)
            dic = {"timestamp": datetime.datetime.now()}
        else:
            (llave, valor) = line.split(":", 1)

        llave = llave.lower()
        if llave in claves and valor:
            dic[claves[llave]] = valor.strip()
```

Al terminar de leer debo agregar a la lista el último diccionario en proceso:

```
if dic:
    lista.append(dic)
```

Y ahora imprimimos el json:

```
json_data = dict(aps=lista)
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, default=str))
```

produce:

```
{
    "aps": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2020-12-08 17:07:53.514575",
            "last_seen": "3492 ms ago",
            "tsf": "16770805099 usec (0d, 04:39:30)",
            "frequency": "2412",
            "beacon_interval": "100 TUs",
            "capability": "ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1431)",
            "signal": "-49.00 dBm",
            "ssid": "Caf\u00e9 Negro",
            "supported_rates": "1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2020-12-08 17:07:53.514596",
            "last_seen": "405 ms ago",
            "tsf": "7141877017905 usec (82d, 15:51:17)",
            "frequency": "5785",
            "beacon_interval": "100 TUs",
            "capability": "ESS Privacy (0x0011)",
            "signal": "-91.00 dBm",
            "ssid": "MOUREY C4",
            "supported_rates": "6.0* 9.0 12.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 48.0 54.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Tal vez no me expliqué, pero tengo que guardar todos los datos. Por eso mi duda era, cómo guardar toda la información incluso cuando un dato no aparece en una red pero en otra sí.

Para el ejemplo puse el dato "DS Parameter set", este dato aparece en una red, pero en la siguiente ya no. Por lo tanto, para la primer red, sí tendrá un valor, pero para la segunda, su valor será "null".

Comment: @HugoZárate. Supongo que si conoces de antemano los datos que te interesan.